# Xamarin Forms Tabbed structure - show same button at bottom of all tabs

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

My xamarin forms application is based on the tabbed structure. What I want to achieve is as follows: I want to show a button at the bottom of all tabbed pages, it should be the same button. When I navigate to other tab, the same button should appear with same logic behind it. How can I achieve this?

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:DriverApp.Views"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DriverApp.ViewModels"
        x:Class="DriverApp.Views.PlanningDetailPage">

<TabbedPage.Children>

    <NavigationPage Title="Activity">
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:ActivityPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>

    <NavigationPage Title="Vehicle">
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:VehiclePage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>

    <NavigationPage Title="Driver">
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:DriverPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>

    <NavigationPage Title="Checklist">
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:CheckListPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>

    <NavigationPage Title="Attachment">
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:AttachmentPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>

    <NavigationPage Title="Damage">
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:DamagePage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</TabbedPage.Children>
```

Comment: create a BasePage that all of your content pages inherit from

Comment: But the content pages all have different bindingcontexes right?

Comment: that's up to you

Comment: Or should I  make use of ControlTemplate in the ResourceDictionary in Application.Resources in App.xaml?

Comment: What do you mean by 'same button'? Is it one same button instance or just buttons that have same appearence and same logic behind? Basically, it's no good to use the same instance, since it will mix up life circles. If you want a same button with same appearance, both BasePage as @Jason mentioned and ControlTemplate will do, but if you want a shared logic behind for button click, ControlTemplate will be a little bit more complex.